# Toggle between cameras, sticks on VideoSourcePlayer.Start()

Tags: .net, video, emgucv, aforge

I have a system with two cameras.I have two VideoSource objects, one of which is displayed in a VideoSourcePlayer control. I want to alternate between them using the following code:

```
videoSourcePlayer.SignalToStop
videoSourcePlayer.WaitForStop();
if (videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource == videoSource1)
{
     videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = videoSource2;
}
else
{
     videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = videoSource1;
}
videoSourcePlayer.Start();
```

When I first press the toggle button, I get the "connecting..." message in the videoSourcePlayer control. This didn't happen when I called videoSourcePlayer.Stop(), which simply threw an exception and then went on. After toggling again, the problem goes away. In other words, I can toggle between the two cameras without any problems.
Can anyone explain this, and tell me how to avoid the issue?

**Clarification**

I initialize the videoSource objects and Player as follows:

```
videoSource1 = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[iiiVideoIndex].MonikerString);
...
videoSource1.NewFrame += iiiFrameHandler.SaveFrame;
videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = videoSource1;
videoSourcePlayer.NewFrame += PlayerNewFrame;
...
videoSource1.Start();
...
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
videoSource2 = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[jjjVideoIndex].MonikerString);
...
videoSource2.NewFrame += jjjFrameHandler.SaveFrame;
videoSource2.Start();
```

I have three newFrameHandlers because there are some things I want to do through the user interface, and some that I want to do, in a certain state, for each frame from each camera.

Answer (score 0):

This would normally work. The problem was that both cameras were connected through an external USB hub. The software could identify both cameras, but could only connect to one at a time.

Connecting one of them to its own USB port made the problem go away.